# The Dalvik classloader (probably) pranking me

Tags: classloader, dexclassloader

I have the following code in Android 4:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertificateEncodingException;
....
public void method(){    
   try { 
   throw new ExtCertificateEncodingException();

   } catch(ExtCertificateEncodingException e){

   } 
}
```

I compiled it and ran it. And an exception was thrown but it wasn't catched. It was confused me a bit. But, after an investigation it turned out that `e` has type `com.android.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertificateEncodingException` (or something like that) instead of  `bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertificateEncodingException`.

And, I don't understand that exactly. I suppose that class loader makes some magic that I cannot understand. After all, I **imported**:
`org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertificateEncodingException`.

1. Please help me understand it, explain it.
2. Why a classloader is not obey and doesn't load it? (I am not sure if my interpretation of that behaviour is ok).
3. Why I cannot `import com.android.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertificateEncodingException`
4. How to catch exactly it? I am not interested in `catch(Exception e)`